# What is the best way to overfit a model with accuracy?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, overfitting

I need to overfit a model to specific data.*(These data have been created from simulation of complex multidimensional models.)*

The final goal is to extract coefficients (betas) to retrieve with accuracy the results of the database, without any complication, any assumptions, any need for extrapolation, just math.

I thought about a regression that try to maximize the adjusted R-squared, as it represents "the proportion of the variance for a dependent variable that's explained by a regression model".

But it may exist some other method, maybe machine learning method, that are more relevant and easy to apply ?

**An important point is that the method have to be easily replicable on a non professionnal software like Excel** **, that why regressions *(that contains coefficients*) interest me.**

Thank you a lot !

Comment: You can add polynomial terms until you hit every point.

Comment: Is there a textbook that covers the topic of on-purpose overfitting? This approach sounds like adversarial learning

Answer (score 0):

My thought is that knowing the generating distribution implies one may be able to use something like factor analysis to derive the sets of variables/factors that account for nearly all of the variability, where such factors are related to the parameters of the generating distribution model which also encompasses a randomness component.

Use this set of factors to derive the regression model.

Put differently, fit as close as possible to the extent of the underlying noise model.

An interpolation model would be a correct approach if there is no (or very little) randomness and a poor choice in the presence of significant random noise.